# Could not load org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKKeyPairGenerator$RSABeanInfo

Tags: java, maven, maven-2, maven-3

While build my application i am getting below error. I search online, i did not find any solution ..........

```
Apr 05, 2013 2:46:34 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader validateJarFile
INFO: validateJarFile(/cisco/software/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/webapps/rmsportal-0.1/WEB-INF/lib/javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) - jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class
Apr 05, 2013 2:46:46 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader loadClass
INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.  Could not load org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.JDKKeyPairGenerator$RSABeanInfo.  The eventual following stack trace is caused by an error thrown for debugging purposes as well as to attempt to terminate the thread which caused the illegal access, and has no functional impact.
java.lang.IllegalStateException
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1599)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader.loadClass(WebappClassLoader.java:1558)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
.
.
.

at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1004)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:310)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:722)

Apr 05, 2013 2:47:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Error listenerStart
Apr 05, 2013 2:47:11 AM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext startInternal
SEVERE: Context [/rmsportal-0.1] startup failed due to previous errors
Apr 05, 2013 2:47:11 AM org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoader clearReferencesJdbc
SEVERE: The web application [/rmsportal-0.1] registered the JDBC driver [org.h2.Driver] but failed to unregister it when the web application was stopped. To prevent a memory leak, the JDBC Driver has been forcibly unregistered.
```

Comment: Can you clarify what build step this is occurring in? It looks like this is a log for some sort of deployment and not a Maven build log. Any other context (more context prior to this error) will help.

Answer (score 0):

The root cause may be the following line

```
INFO: validateJarFile(/cisco/software/apache-tomcat-7.0.37/.../WEB-INF/lib/
      javax.servlet-api-3.0.1.jar) -  
      jar not loaded. See Servlet Spec 2.3, section 9.7.2. 
      Offending class: javax/servlet/Servlet.class

INFO: Illegal access: this web application instance has been stopped already.
```

I understand that you have configure the `javax.servlet-api-3.0.1` as a `compile` scope. Please try to change it to `provided` scope.

I hope this may help.